# what is the correct way to update a docker image

Tags: docker

I created an ubuntu docker container, copied a mirror of a c++ library (sized 1.2 gb) I'll be using on it (on the docker container's home directory), built it on it and forgot to remove the mirror before creating the image and pushing to docker hub.

I then tried to re-run the container from the image to remove the c++ mirror so i can commit the new image , but the new image didn't downsize for a reason i ignore . After i run `docker images` i still have :

```
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tawfik741/opencascade-build   amd64               74f333aa7293        16 minutes ago      1.79GB
```

The commands i ran are :

- Creating the container with :

```
docker run --name opencascade-build -it ubuntu:latest bash
```

- Copying the C++ library mirror so i build it on the container :

```
docker cp opencascade-dev-mirror [my-container-id]:/home
```

- After building my library i did :

```
sudo docker commit --author "Tawfik" --message "opencascade-build" [my-container-id] tawfik741/opencascade-build:amd64
```

- and pushed it to a private repo with :

```
docker push tawfik741/opencascade-build:amd64
```

after figuring up that i forgot to remove that `opencascade-dev-mirror` from the container i decided to run the container , remove it , and save the new image , i tried in to save a new image but it's exactly the same size as the old one :

- I ran the docker container from the image with :

```
docker run -it tawfik741/opencascade-build:amd64 /bin/bash
```

- I updated the container then ran :

```
docker commit --author "Onboard SARL" --message "opencascade-build" [my-container's id] tawfik741/opencascade-build:correction-amd64-correction
```

but the `tawfik741/opencascade-build:amd64-correction` has the same size as the `tawfik741/opencascade-build:amd64` image .

Comment: Do you use docker build to create image? Do you have Dockerfile ?

Comment: I didn’t use a dockerfile for this one .

Comment: If you want to remove an image, you should run `docker image rm IMAGE_ID`, and in your case `docker image rm 74f333aa7293`.

Comment: @MarkoE i of course read the docs before coming to ask a question hear , I don’t want to remove the image , I want to update it

Comment: You need to start over from scratch: you cannot edit or update an existing image.  Can you edit the question to include the specific set of commands you used to create the image?  (You might then look at Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial; that description will be very close to a reproducible Dockerfile that you can `docker build` to get a clean image.)

Comment: in addition to @MarkoE, Hint: just the first 3 characters are important, like `docker image rm -f 74f` ;)

Comment: @DavidMaze for this case , I didn’t create a dockerfile for now since I need to iterate fast and I’m using a very big c++ library in local that I need to copy and and build to my image and using a dockerfile would mean that I’ll need to read the context for 1.2 gb each I time I debug the dockerfile which makes hard to debug for now . I don’t understand why it’s not possible to update an image since i know that a container is just a stateful image and therefore I thought It should be able to be saved again to a new image somehow. I updated my questions with the set of docker commands

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I don’t want to remove the image , just update it or a save a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit, modify, or update an image once you've created it.

You can create a new image based on an existing image.  The way Docker works internally, the new image always contains the entire old image, plus a description of what changed from the old image.  Doing this never makes the new image smaller, only larger.

You need to start over and create a new image starting from the original base image.  If you use the standard `docker build` command and Dockerfile system, it should be enough to delete the `COPY` line that adds the large file to the image and rebuild.  If you're using `docker commit`, you need to completely start over and hope you repeat the same manual commands in the same way; even if you're trying to "iterate rapidly" you'll be much better off switching to a Dockerfile.

Comment: then what does docker commit do?

Comment: That is how you loook on it. If, by editing you mean creating new image on base of existing, you can edit :)

Comment: `docker commit` creates a new image from a container by recording the additional changes from the base image.  It is not reproducible and has some other shortcomings, and you should almost always prefer `docker build`.